# Updating $scope after $HTTP.post

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

new at this.

I have 2 div's;
When I use one to post new value into the server, the post action works fine.

How do ensure this post updates the scope in the other div? (to update the div with the new entry using ng-repeat)

The HTTP.post action seems to be working as the data appears on refresh.

I have tried $scope.apply() but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
// this is the controller to get the data from the server
  app.controller('projectsController', 
       function projectsController($scope, projectsFactory){ 
               $scope.projects =    projectsFactory.query();
       });
```

and the factory to get the data from server

```
    app.factory('projectsFactory', 
       function($resource,localStorage, $rootScope, $http){
         return $resource('/api/project:id', {id: '@id'});
        });
```

This is the controller to take the user input and post to back to the server

```
     app.controller('projectEditController', function($scope, projectEdit){
                $scope.projectEdit =    projectEdit;
     });
```

And the service to post the data to the server

```
         app.service('projectEdit', 
                   function projectEdit(localStorage,$rootScope, $http) {

        var self = this;

        self.add = function(newProject,projects) {
            newProject = angular.copy(newProject);

              var newProject = (JSON.stringify(newProject));

        return $http.post('/api/project', newProject )
                    .then(function(response) {
                     newProject.id = response.data.id;

    });

};
```

Which seems to be fine as it posts the data to the Sever fine.

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the 
"$scope.projects =   projectsFactory.query();" to update once the post operation is complete.

this will update the display in the HTML, which is the goal.

Hopefully this is an easy solve for a good developer, but I am stumped!
Thanks for your time.

Conor

Comment: You could `$broadcast` an event and attach the results to it.  Then in your controller you listen (`$on`) for the event and act appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 wrapper div, and set your controller to it with ng-controller.
Put your 2 divs in the wrapper div. Now the scope created by your controller is available in both divs, this is the easy way. When something updates data in that scope, and you have other things in the dom referencing that variable, then the dom will refresh like you want.
If you really want different controllers for each child div, that's fine, just be careful around inherited scopes. It really is much easier to just have one controller in a situation like this.
By the way, I saw that you mentioned scope.apply(). Be careful, apply() is a real javascript function, and NOT the one you want. You should call scope.$apply(), $apply is the angular function, and to avoid confusion, you could call scope.$digest instead.

Comment: Thanks a million, my code was not well indented, so re-wrote it.